# Chemical formula of Lactic acid

Tags: structural-formula

Formula of Lactic acid is given as C3H6O3, can't this be divided by the common factor3, and written as CH2O?

Comment: This was supposed to be a _molecular_ formula. You don't divide molecules.

Comment: FWIW, CH2O is the correct "empirical formula" for lactic acid, as you would calculate from elemental analysis.

Comment: Basically, you can simplify or "divide" a molecular formula only if it really makes sense.

Comment: Basically, a given molecule has a unique (molecular) formula. However, some molecules have a tendency to associate to form bigger molecules. Only in that case can you simplify or "divide" a molecular formula. For example, elemental sulfur (S) is usually found in nature as S8 and then you can consider its true formula is S. Also P4S10 is a dimer of P2O5; you have P4S10 in your flask but you can consider P2O5 in your calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have initially tagged your question "structural formula", however $\ce{C3H6O3}$ is somewhat ambigous in this respect, and besides [lactic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactic_acid) can represent its isomer [3-hydroxypropionic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-Hydroxypropionic_acid), methoxyacetic acid, and almost completely different compounds like [dihydroxyacetone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihydroxyacetone), [dimethyl carbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimethyl_carbonate), [glyceraldehyde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyceraldehyde) or [trioxanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trioxane), not speaking of the second one $\ce{CH2O}$ ([formaldehyde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formaldehyde) or [ethylene oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene_oxide)). Well, these are not structural formulas at all.